# Does Baruch HaShem Le'Olam (Ma'ariv; Ashkenazi) count as Birchoth Keriath Shema'?

Tags: halacha, blessing, shema, hefsek-interruption

Does Baruch HaShem Le'Olam have the same Din as Birchoth Keriath Shema' in terms of interruption?

If you are in the middle of the Berachah, do you respond to the same things as you would if you were saying Shema' UVirchothehah, or can you respond to things more liberally like other types of Berachoth?

The reason I ask is that I was advised long ago to skip it if I'm falling behind, since so many communities don't say it at all because they view the Berachah itself as an interruption, whereas one may not skip the other Berachoth (like Hashkivenu) because that would break up the order of Birchoth Keriath Shema'.

Comment: I don't follow what the issue of skipping it when late has to do with the level of interruption permitted during it.

Comment: What other brachot have more lenient rules regarding interruption during the bracha than birkot keriat shema?

Comment: @doubleaa, to your first point, is my edit better? To your second, Pesukei DeZimra, for example.

Comment: ?? Pesukei Dezimra is not a bracha. Re your edit: so you're trying to measure how integral BHL is by comparing it's status vis a vis interruptions? If so I still think it could be clearer in the Q.

Comment: PD"Z is two Berachoth HaSemuchoth LeHavertan, is it not? And no, I'm comparing its importance and wondering how that affects its rules vis a vis interruptions.

Comment: PDZ does have two brachot hasemuchot, but if you'll notice, most of the middle is not and has the same interruption rules as...bein haperakim! So I only see two categories ever: interrupting the middle of a bracha, and interrupting a connection between brachot. These two categories apply equally to PDZ and BKSh. IIRC they also apply to bentching, hallel and other places like that (Shemone esrei of course being the obvious exception for its own reason.)

Comment: I think your question is valuable in determining the relationship of the psukim part to the bracha part of BHL, but I don't know that it's the best metric for measuring its value as a BKSh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Aruch HaShulchan OC [236:12](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7705&st=&pgnum=433) rules that in between each of the 18 verses of Baruch HaShem Le'Olam is considered like "between the chapters" regarding interruptions, and that during the paragraph begininning Yir'u Eineinu is considered like "in the midst of the chapters" regarding interruptions.

Comment: Awesome answer. Just what I was looking for. I'm just waiting to see if there are any others.