# When do you interrupt to answer Kaddish?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, kaddish, hefsek-interruption

Often I find myself in the middle of some part of davening when the chazzan starts saying kaddish. Should I interrupt to answer or does it depend on which part of davening I am holding?

Comment: I think there's an answer here about this somewhere.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11429/759

Comment: sort of related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17486/759

Comment: Are you asking about specific parts of kaddish, eg. Yehei Shmei Rabbah?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different rules depending on which part of Davening you are up to, and the rules also depend on which part of Kaddish is being said.

During preliminary parts of Davening (Berachoth, Korbanoth, Pesukei DeZimra, etc.):

- Interrupt for any Amen

During Keriath Shema' UVirkotheha:

- Interrupt **between paragraphs** (this is a technical term, not
  determined by the page layout of your Siddur) for:

  - Any Amen
- Interrupt **between verses** (still technical, but a lot more
  intuitive than "between paragraphs") for:

  - Amen YeHei Shmeih Rabba
  - DaAmiran Be'Alma VeImru Amen

During Shemoneh 'Esreh:

- During the **actual 'Amidah**:

  - DON'T INTERRUPT
- During **Elokai Netzor**:

  - Interrupt between verses as in Keriath Shema'
- After Yihyu LeRatzon (at the end of Elokai Netzor):

  - Interrupt for any Amen

SOURCES: Memory of the rules printed in Artscroll and [Siddur Tefillath Yosef](http://www.mysefer.com/popuplargeimage.asp?strImage=3879.jpg&strImageType=product&strPageTitle=Siddur%20Tefilat%20Yosef%20with%20Piskei%20Mishnah%20Berurah%20%28Ashkenaz%20-%20small%20size%29), as well as Jewish day school instruction from years ago.  I believe their source is primarily Mishnah Berurah, but see the M"B itself for more details and slight differences of opinion brought by the Magen Avraham and Peri Megadim.  Also see the Shu"'A and RaM"A for slight differences.  First see [O"C 66:3 and M"B there](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=285) for the rules of interrupting K"S, then see [O"C 122:1 and M"B 4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=285) who equates Elokai Netzor to K"S.  M"B on 66:3 also give a few Kol SheKeins about "Tahanunim" and Pesukei DeZimra.

Comment: is this interrupting for Amen to a blessing or Amen to Kaddish or both?

Comment: @nikmasi, if I'm not mistaken, wherever it says "any Amen", it means for any Berachah to HaShem (as opposed to, say, a MiSheBerach).

Comment: @nikmasi, also note that there are a few other responses that are allowed during Tefillah that follow similar patterns, including Barechu, Modim, HaKel HaKadosh, Birkoth HaTorah, etc.

Comment: forgive my ignorance but does kaddish qualify as a bracha? if i say yisgadel v'yisgadash... it is a bracha levatalah?

Comment: @nikmasi, it is a Davar SheBiKdushah, which needs to be recited with a Minyan, but no, it is not a Berachah. The Amens of generic Berachoth, though, follow the same rules as the "regular" Amens of Kaddish (ie., other than Yehei Shmeih Rabbah and DaAmiran Be'Alma).

Comment: Thanks if you could add the source in M"B i'll mark as accepted.

Comment: @nikmasi, done.

Comment: @SethJ Are you counting the first amen in kaddish (...shmeih rabbah -- amen) as a regular amen? What about the amens for the 2/3 verses after daamiran bealma?

Comment: @DoubleAA, M"B doesn't mention Shmeih Rabba explicitly, but he does call the others Minhag.

Comment: @SethJ So are you saying they count as 'any amen'?

Comment: @DoubleAA, that's how I understand them.

Comment: @SethJ I would have thought that Amens that are midina are permitted and amens that are minhag would be like baruch hu uvaruch shemo and forbidden.

Comment: @DoubleAA, where?  Bein HaPerakim?

Comment: @SethJ Yes. Would you say bhuv"sh during Bein HaPerakim?

Comment: The chart in the Chabad siddur (presumably based on S"A HaRav) doesn't make an exception between birchos krias shema.

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Mordechai Eliyahu, in the appendix to his edition of Kitzur Shulchan Aruch, prints a table for when this is permitted (Ashkenazi one from A. Bloom publishers, Sefardi one by himself). Remarkably, it is available online (p. 685 of [this pdf](http://www.israel613.com/books%5CKITZUR_SHULCHAN_ELIYAHU.CV.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

Both Sidur Koren and Sidur Tefilas Kol Pe have a table that shows exactly where one should or should not interrupt for Kaddish. I will attempt to summarize later or see if I can find the table online.