# Answering an essential answer while in the middle of another

Tags: halacha, tefilla, kaddish, hefsek-interruption, kedusha-prayer

Some congregational responses are of the "highest level"; [required](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23508/3073) except in special circumstances, like during *sh'mone esrei*, in the beginning of *krias sh'ma*, and in the middle of a short *bracha*.

Some occur in pairs with relatively short time in-between:

1. Kaddish: *Amen, yehei sh'meih rabba* and *Amen* after *D'amiran b'alma, v'imru*
2. Kedusha: *Kadosh kadosh kadosh* and *Baruch k'vod*

If the chazzan is so fast that, at the time for the second response, a congregant is still in the middle of his first response, how should he act?

<sup>(There may even be a difference between the two examples, as *kaddish* may be interrupted for other responses, whereas *kedusha* may not.)</sup>

Comment: I guess you could ask the same question if you're hearing 2 Minyanim at the same time; and does "your Minyan" take precedence?

Comment: @DannySchoemann Well, or if two are saying _kaddish_ out of sync. But then we know to answer _Amen_ for each only if there is more than _toch k'dei dibur_ in between. Here, I will not have opportunity to answer the same response later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the congregation finished the second response before the congregant finished the first response then he "loses" out. Otherwise he can respond both responses back-to-back.

Answer provided by a rabbi on [pocketrabbi.com](http://www.pocketrabbi.com)  a quick response system for answering halachic or any torah questions that a Jew might have.

Comment: So you used an online forum to answer a question in an online forum ? cute :)

Comment: Can this rabbi explain his reasoning? None of us know him. Why should we trust him? Because he styles himself "rabbi"?

Comment: Does the Pocket Rabbi have a name?

Comment: @NBZ See the lower part of the following page http://www.pocketrabbi.com/aboutus.html .